# Serialize the whole class as a String field instead of a JSON Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jax-rs, jboss-eap-6

I have an object that uses a class instance as a wrapper for the String type. How would I serialize my class into a JSON object using JAX-RS and Java EE 6 by using only the toString() method without creating a JSON object for the class and each fields?

Class to be serialized:

```
public class Text {
    private String content;
    protected Text( String content ) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public static Text from( String content ) {
        return new Text( "The text content");
    }
    // This is a method that is used by the subclass and has no meaning for serialization
    protected String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    // This should be used to serialize this class into a String, instead of an object
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Parent class that uses the class to be serialized:

```
public class EditorStoryChapterInput {
    private Text title;
    public Text getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Result expected: I want to serialize as `{ "title": "The text content" }` instead of `{ "title": { content: "the text content" } }`.

EDIT: Looking in the Jackson FAQ I found something useful, and what I want is probably the equivalent of what I found, **but inside a JAX-RS/Java EE 6 environment** in **JBoss EAP 6.1**. There is nothing as `@JsonValue` in my classpath using **JBoss EAP 6.1**:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Serializing_values_as_simple_types

Comment: I'm confused by your edit. Does it mean your problem is solved?

Comment: No, that's Jackson, I want to do that using JAX-RS in JBoss. I edited again to make it clear.

Comment: JBoss will already have a Jackson provider built in. But you still need the Jackson dependency in your project, in order to compile using the Jackson annotations. So if you are using Maven, you can just grab the dependency and give it a `provided` scope.

Comment: Is there a spec compliant way to serialize it in the way I want to? It seems a pretty common use case.

Comment: I don't know about spec compliant, but I just tested it, adding the Jackson dependency to my project, and just putting the `@JsonValue` over the `toString()` link mentioned in the link, and it works fine. Like I said, JBoss is using Jackson under the hood to do the serializing. So there's nothing wrong with using it in your project. You just need to add the dependency in order to compile the annotation. You can get it straight from the server modules if you need to do. But it'll be easier to just use Maven

Comment: Then if you answer the question with the given example and nobody point something spec compliant, then I am going to accept it.

Comment: Give me a bit, I'll work on a more complete answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, I will be waiting for that :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From Comments:**

> I don't know about spec compliant, but I just tested it, adding the Jackson dependency to my project, and just putting the `@JsonValue` over the `toString()` like mentioned in [the link](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQ#Serializing_values_as_simple_types), and it works fine. Like I said, JBoss is using Jackson under the hood to do the serializing. So there's nothing wrong with using it in your project. You just need to add the dependency in order to compile the annotation. You can get it straight from the server modules if you need to do. But it'll be easier to just use Maven

Here are the classes I used for the example. I'll post the classes, then I point out how to get the dependencies.

Your `Text` class

```
/** Getter and Setters added for Jackson discovery **/
public class Text {

    private String content;

    public void setContent(String content) { this.content = content; }
    protected String getContent() { return content; }

    @Override @JsonValue
    public String toString() { return content; }
}
```

Your `EditorStoryChapterInput` class

```
public class EditorStoryChapterInput {

    private Text title;

    public void setTitle(Text title) { this.title = title; }
    public Text getTitle() { return title; }
}
```

The resource class

```
@Path("/json")
public class JsonResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getJson() {
        EditorStoryChapterInput input = new EditorStoryChapterInput();
        Text title = new Text();
        title.setContent("Hello World");
        input.setTitle(title);
        return Response.ok(input).build();
    }
}
```

The `Application` class to register out resource

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JsonApplication extends Application  {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(JsonResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

**Get the Dependencies**

If you are using Maven, you just need the `jackson-core-asl` artifact. When I use JBoss, I prefer to use their boms, so they can manage the versions. So What your pom would look something like (Remember I said we can use `provide` scope, because JBoss already has these dependencies. We just need it to compile)

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ... Other dependencies
</dependencies>
```

If you're not using Maven, you can simply look inside

> `${eap-home-dir}\modules\system\layers\base\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\main`

There you will find the `jackson-core-asl-1.9.9.redhat-3.jar`. Just add that to your project however you normally add jars to your project. Tested this approach, with same result

[image]

Let me know if you have any problems adding the dependency.

---

### UPDATE: Without using Jackson (no third party dependencies)

We can use the [Java API for JSON Processing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html), and implement our own [`MessageBodyWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html), which will be used from writing the `EditorStoryChapterInput` object to the response `OutputStream`. It might look something like

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TextMessageBodyWriter 
    implements MessageBodyWriter<EditorStoryChapterInput> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return type == EditorStoryChapterInput.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(EditorStoryChapterInput t, Class<?> type, 
            Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(EditorStoryChapterInput input, Class<?> type,
            Type type1, Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, 
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> mm, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        Text title = input.getTitle();
        JsonObject jsonObject = 
                Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("title", title.toString()).build();

        try (JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(out)) {
            jsonWriter.writeObject(jsonObject);
        }
    }
}
```

When searching for `MessageBodyWriters`, JAX-RS will look at the `@Produces` annotation to see what type it produces, and if it matches the `@Produces` method on our resource method, the writer will be put into a list for the framework to traverse. Next it will check the `isWritable` method on each of the writers. If it returns true, then that's the writer it will use. In our case, we return true if the return type of the response body is of `EditorStoryChapterInput` type.

In the `writeTo` method, we use the Java JSON Processing API to create a `JsonObject` and write it to the `OutputStream` provided to us by the framework.

Then we can register the writer with the application

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class TextApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(JsonResource.class);
        classes.add(TextMessageBodyWriter.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

Testing it with the same `JsonResource` class from above, we get the output

```
{"title":"Hello World"}
```

---

- [Jersey has a good tutorial for MessageBodyWriters/MessageBodyReaders](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html)
- [Resteasy's tutorial is not as well explained as Jersey's](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Content_Marshalling_Providers.html#Content_Marshalling_with__Provider_classes)
- [Also see Java EE's tutorial for JSON Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm)

Comment: Note, I'm using EAP 6.3. I don't think 6.1 should give any different result.

Comment: Genius, sadly this is not portable. I will be starting a bounty to see if anyone comes up with a portable solution, but your answer is definitely correct.

Comment: You don't have to use JBoss dependencies. You can grab the official Jackson implementation. I'm sure there's a way, to do the same, using JAXB annotations, as JBoss should have a provider to to convert the JAXB annotations to json, but if you were to try and port the application to a different server, you would need to make sure the server has such provider implementation. Otherwise, you will still need another dependency. Json serialization isn't part of the jax-rs spec, at least AFAIK. So Every server will have a different implementation (if any).

Comment: "I'm sure there's a way, to do the same, using JAXB annotations"

I have looked a lot for it, maybe I did not find it because of my lack of knowledge in JAXB.

U say Java EE does not have JSON serialization, but all these classes are inside `javax.ws.rs` package:  `@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )`

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment. _JAXB to JSON conversion_ is not mandated as a requirement of the jax-rs spec, though many implementations will use [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/) to support marshalling JAXB annotated classes. That said, I am not sure the how the conversion is done. If the specific conversion you are looking for it not possible with any arrangement of annotations, you may have to implement your own conversion provider, with the Java standard JSON processing API (if you don't want any dependencies).

Comment: Ok, I removed the mark as the correct question earlier just to start the bounty, but it seems your comment satisfies the "portable" requirement I was going to request. By the way, it would be very useful if you could enhance this answer and provide an example of using a provider in a portable way, for posterity.

Comment: Have a look at my latest **UPDATE**